# Searching a string in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to learn shell script. So sorry if my question is so simple.

I am having a file called one.txt and if either strings 1.2 or 1.3 is present in the string then I have to display the success message else the failure message.

The code I tried is follows,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "checking"
if grep -q 1.2 /root/one | grep -q 1.3 /root/one; then
echo " vetri Your NAC version"
fi
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Use `||` instead of `|`. `||` is the `or` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also include the OR in your grep pattern like so:

```
grep '1.2\|1.3' /root/one
```

details [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/)

Update:
as twalberg pointed out in the comment, my answer was not precise enough. The better pattern is:

```
grep '1\.2\|1\.3' /root/one
```

Or even better, because more compact:

```
grep '1\.[23]' /root/one
```

Comment: Or even `grep '1\.[23]' /root/one`... Since the dot would allow matches on "1a3" or "1+3", etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `||`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "checking"
if grep -q 1.2 /root/one || grep -q 1.3 /root/one; then
echo " vetri Your NAC version"
fi
```

Single `|` operator is called pipe. It will pass the output of the command before `|` to the command after `|`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to join these these greps with `|` (OR operator):

```
grep '1.2\|1.3'
```

or

```
grep -E '1.2|1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easier way to do this is to create a variable to check the count of occurrences:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "checking"
CHECK=`egrep -c '1\.(2|3)' /root/one`
if [ "$CHECK" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "vetri Your NAC version"
fi
```